# Preserve semantic info about React components in the rendered HTML?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, selenium, webpack

In newer Angular, the tags/names of the used components are preserved in the outputted HTML:

```
<Invoice>
  <div class="itemlist">
    <InvoiceItem>
       <span>...</span>       <span>...</span>       <span>...</span>
    </InvoiceItem>
    <InvoiceItem>
       <span>...</span>       <span>...</span>       <span>...</span>
    </InvoiceItem>
  </div>
</Invoice>
```

but in React this information is stripped out, leaving only divs and spans with no way to tell what component ended where.

```
  <div class="itemlist">
       <span>...</span>       <span>...</span>       <span>...</span>
       <span>...</span>       <span>...</span>       <span>...</span>
  </div>
```

Is there a way to restore this information, either as tags or as data-* attributes?

(I'm using React / webpack / Typescript / Selenium.)

EDIT: I'm fine with having to add stuff to the build-pipeline to make this happen.  Especially since the names of classes are mangled during minification it may be required anyway. Unless React / ReactDOM have a solution in place for this somewhere like AngularJS did and Angular4+ always does?

Comment: One way is for you to pass it as props to `InvoiceItem` and let the component use it in the first node in it's html. `<div data-custom-id={this.props.id}>`

Comment: Can u show detail what u expect?

Comment: I'm looking for an automatic solution, since it should work app-wide without editing 1000 files.

Comment: The components themselves won't use the info. Outside processes like Selenium would.

Answer (score 0):

Closest solution I've found so far is https://github.com/Igorbek/typescript-plugin-styled-components which does this for `styled-components` but not React's usual components.

It didn't work with our build process -- I couldn't even get it to compile its own example after cloning it -- but is otherwise what I'm aiming for.